# Implement function for a struct returning a specific generic type

Tags: rust

I am trying to return exclusively a `f32` in my `new` function, inside an impl for `Test` struct. I am sure this isn't the best way to do it since I can call it with any type I want in the turbofish. Could you suggest me a better way of doing the same thing keeping the function as an impl of `Test`? Thanks.

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Test<T> {
        field: T
    }
    
    impl<T> Test<T> {
        fn new() -> Test<f32> {
            Test{field: 3_f32}
        }
    }
    
    let b = Test::<i16>::new(); // i16 or i32 or whatever
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `Test::<i16>::new()` to return?

Comment: `Test{field: 3_f32}`. I wish to only call `Test::new()` and it to return the same but the compiler complains about type inference, so I had to turbofish a dummy type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `struct` is generic, but your `impl` doesn't have to be.

```rust
impl Test<f32> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Test { field: 3. }
    }
}
```

Now, `Test::new()` will compile without any turbofish and the type is always `Test<f32>`.